# What causes a .pyc to become "empty"?

Tags: python

What would cause a compiled python file (.pyc) to lose all its contents, but remain importable?

This has happened to our team several times now, with no discernable pattern in frequency, location, or scope.

The only consistency we've seen is:

- The source file (.py) has **not** been changed for several months, so there should have been no reason for the pyc to suddenly be recompiled.
- the module imports, but has no attributes, methods, classes, etc.  Running dir() on the module returns only: `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']`
- the size of the pyc always reduces to 1 KB

It almost seems like its the result of compiling a blank .py file.  But why?

Some more details:

- using python 2.6+.
- While it's true that some of our packages are loaded into different interpreters (some specific to an application, such as Maya's mayapy), over a network, I've just experienced the above problem on some **local** files, one's which are **only ever hit by a single interpreter** to boot.

So while loading into different interpreters may be "risky"; it's certainly not the cause of at least two cases of the above problem.

-- The only other thing I can point to as *maybe* being problematic is on occasion two instance of the interpreter may be running at the same time (in separate processes).  Even if this were the problem (I'm not certain it is), would there be a way around it?

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Comment: touché.  Scripts are written with 2.6+ in mind, but may be run by a variety of interpreters.  We write for different software packages and some use their own interpreters.  That said, they're all hitting these modules ALL the time, so it's not like someone suddenly fired a suspect interpreter up.

Comment: The 2.x versions of Python all use the same `pyc` filename, though they'll put their version in the bytecode so other versions know to recompile from the source. (Python 3 introduced the `__pycache__` folder which can hold many `pyc` files with the version tags in their names, to avoid all the recompilation.) My guess would be that your module crashes some of the times it is run, but not other times, and the nearly empty `pyc` file is the result of a failed attempt at re compiling it when it is run with a different version than the previous `pyc` file had.

Comment: I know this question is two years old but did you have any luck finding out what was causing this? I've just ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any conclusive evidence, we’d decided the problem was with our file server, or...something. Maybe date stamp differences between OSes?  Something.

We’re now avoiding the problem by setting the **PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE** environment var to prevent the pyc files from being generated in the first place.

EDIT: (props to @zhangyangyu for the bugtracker find!)

On the other hand if you're reading this from the future, and upgrading to the latest version of Python 2.7 is an option, it looks like this bug was [identified back in Sept. 2015](https://bugs.python.org/issue25083) (patch submitted later that year) -- and was merged Nov. 2018.

It's looking like this fix will be included in 2.7.16, which is slated to come out early 2019.

Comment: @Adam Henderson   I've encounterd the same problem in our production environment, but our pyc file is not 1KB large. The root cause is a bug in py2 interpreter, see https://bugs.python.org/issue25083